# jquery 1.8 compatible fadeOut and remove

Tags: jquery

since the new jquery is out, many of the animations with jquery gives error in firefox. I am using this code which I made and its also giving some problem with firefox thought when I only use `remove()` it works but with `fadeOut` it does not works. here is my code

```
$("#"+d).fadeOut(300,function(){$("#"+d).remove();});
```

can anyone suggest me a better code alternative to this. jquery 1.8 compatible. (it works in chrome but not firefox)

here is my full code

```
$(document).on("click", ".glbhn", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var d=$(this).attr('id');
var a=$('.gvpgvpxgvp').val();
var nt ='Global';
var info = 'type=' + nt + '&nid=' + d + '&a=' + a;

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "example.php",
   data: info,
   success: function(html){
$("#"+d).fadeOut(300,function(){$("#"+d).remove();});   
 totalcounter(a);
   $('.globbl').html(html);
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: Does $("#"+d).fadeOut(300); work?

Comment: $("#"+d).fadeOut(300,function(){$(this).remove();}); If that doesn't work, console.log( $("#"+d) );

Comment: it works in chrome but not in firefox . if i remove fadeOut it works in firefox too

Comment: Even if you try $("#"+d).fadeOut(300); ?

Comment: btw param is it still nsidomerror you get in firefox?

Comment: $("#"+d).fadeOut(300); yes this works , but not with remove in firefox . i think my code is too old for the new jquery . any better code ?

Comment: @ParamVeer Singh Tillon: Try This: $("#"+d).fadeOut(function(){$("#"+d).remove();}, 300);

Comment: i can think... the problem is because u r removing it - i will try  to think of one to get rid of ur error even with remove, hold on... do u have to have remove too after animation of hiding fadeout???

Comment: yes . the same error friend . i really need animation here atleast , i cant avoid the animations all the time

Comment: maybe i got it just a few mor emoments

Comment: Ctrl+C Ctrl+V of your code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/uDvFu/) works in my Firefox (18 nightly). Try on yours.

Comment: Also, jQuery 1.8.1 is released and fixes many bugs. But that's probably unrelated to your question, my bet is that you have an error somewhere which Chrome ignores. Check your Firefox console/Firebug for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (using Firefox 14). Are you sure you have included the jQuery script (via the `link` tag) and included the code inside `$(document).ready()`? You can also install Firebug to see errors.

Or maybe the variable `d` is not defined, or no such id exists?

Comment: d is a defined variable and yes i have jquery included and also the $(document).ready() my post says its working in chrome but not firefox

Comment: that shouldnt be a problem.it works for me even if d is undefined...trust me his issue is very  strange

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
var interval = 0;
function myfrnd(){
       if( $("#" + d).css('display','none')){
                $(this).remove();
                clearInterval(interval);
        }
}

$("#"+d).bind('myfrndevt',function(){
            interval = setInterval(function(){
                                      myfrnd();
                                     },1000);
 });

$("#"+d).fadeOut(300,function(){
                        $(this).trigger('myfrndevt');
});
```

Comment: omg u related this with my old code . no no i can work it without the animation , this one is a seperate one with different code. well thank you for taking out time for this one also

Comment: this is code i just wrote from scratch right now, i made up names like that just for fun ;) . i cant test it, I *never* get your error. This is with animation AND to remove the element since it seems u need both. Does this one work or still u get nsidomerror?

Comment: yes is different i just wrote it and it is for your specific case about animation AND removing element (if you need just fadeout animation, just do $("#"+d).fadeOut(300); and you're done, would be WAY easier - because it would still be a fade out animation, and it will end up being invisible ((are you sure u have to remove element too from DOM?)) ), i hope it works to get rid of nsidomerror let me know if my code above worked

Comment: yes i want to remove it from DOM Too. ill try this code when i reach home at office now , will def tell you thanks a lot for helping out

Comment: sorry to say this friend . u helped a lot but this does not fix the issue . well i think i have to say good bye to animations for a while . i tried it in my dad's laptop in Firefox too. still didn't worked out

Comment: Maybe so. Quick experiment: I wonder if your firefoxes hate removing a display:none element because it messes up its internal styling functions. The problem is something to do with animations *combined with* DOM and, perhaps more particularly, **style** (also look elsewhere in your code, disable ALL styles, etc. - or was that your only code?) Also, try this: Instead of $(this).remove() in my code try $(this).css('visibility','hidden').css('display','block').remove(); or try just $(this).css('display','block').remove();(if that works, that'd be weird wouldn't it?)

Comment: I say **your** firefoxes because I have yet to see this problem ever with my firefox, even with new Jquery. I sure hope I don't start seeing this problem myself, lol, that is some real trouble you have there. Try first disable *all* other code, or at least all other styles (you can disable styles programatically like this in console: http://www.compucraft.com.au/dev/DisableStyles.htm but to be sure, better try to disable all other code altogether from loading just in case)